# How many Friday 13ths in a year?

Tags: ruby, date

The only thing that is wrong in this code is the return :P

How would you display how many Friday 13ths there in a year?

```
def unlucky_days(year)
    require 'date'

  start_date = Date.new(year)
  end_date = Date.new(year+1)
  my_fridays = [4]
  thirteen = "13"
  result = (start_date..end_date).to_a.select {|k| my_fridays.include?(k.wday) && thirteen.include?(k.strftime('%d'))}

  result.length


end
```

Comment: What do you mean by "The only thing that is wrong in this code is the return"? You're returning `result.length`, so you're going to get a number. Have you tried just returning `result`?

Comment: Sorry! Updated description to describe problem better. Wanted the total number of 13ths in a year.

Comment: First, Friday's wday number is 5, not 4.  Second, why are you doing `Array#include?` and `String#include?` instead of just a simple equality test?

Comment: Thanks Mark! Include cause I was first checking other dates as well

Answer (score 4):

I'd write:

```
require 'date'
(1..12).count { |month| Date.new(year, month, 13).friday? }
```

Answer (score 3):

+1 to @MarkReed's comments. Also, why call `.to_a` on a range, and why use variables when the [Date class in Ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html) already has methods like `.day` and `.friday`? Here is how I would do it:

```
def unlucky_days(year)
  s = Date.new(year, 1, 1)
  e = Date.new(year, 12, 31)
  ((s...e).select {|d| d.friday? && d.day == 13 }).count
end
```

Comment: Amazing! As you can probably see I am really new to this (pure hobby) but every day I am just stunned by the flexibility and elegance of code!!!! :D thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your code is wrong on a few points.

> 1. Friday is weekday number 5, not 4.
> 2. Why `[4].include?(n)` instead of just `n==4`?
> 3. `"13".include?("#{n}")` is not just strange but incorrect, since it returns true for 1 and 3 as well as 13.

You can go cut down on the level of brute force by just looking at the twelve 13ths and counting how many are Fridays, rather than looking at all 365 or 366 days and seeing which of them are both 13th's and Fridays, as in @tokland's answer, reproduced here:

```
def unlucky_days(year)
  (1..12).count { |month| Date.new(year, month, 13).friday? }
end
```

Or, since there are only 14 possibilities, you could also just use a prebuilt table:

```
# number of Friday the 13ths in a given year is given by
# UnluckyDays[weekday of Jan 1][0 if common, 1 if leap] 
UnluckyDays = [ [2,3], [2,2], [2,1], [1,2], [3,2], [1,1], [1,1] ]
def unlucky_days(year) 
  UnluckyDays[Date.new(year,1,1).wday][Date.leap?(year) ? 1 : 0 ]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a variant of @Tokland's answer.

```
require 'date'

def count_em(year)
  d = Date.new(year, 1, 13) << 1
  12.times.count { (d >>= 1).friday? }
end

(2010..2016).each { |y| puts "%d Friday the 13ths in %s" % [count_em(y), y] }
  # 1 Friday the 13ths in 2010
  # 1 Friday the 13ths in 2011
  # 3 Friday the 13ths in 2012
  # 2 Friday the 13ths in 2013
  # 1 Friday the 13ths in 2014
  # 3 Friday the 13ths in 2015
  # 1 Friday the 13ths in 2016
```

If this calculation (or one like it) were done often and performance was important, two hashes could be constructed, one for leap years, the other for non-leap years, with keys the day of week on which the first day of the year falls and the values the number of Friday the 13ths in such years.